# Delete a character before another character

Tags: php, string, str-replace, trim

I need to delete comma `,` before each closing bracket `)`.

Example string:

`$string = "('abc', 'def', 'gah',), ('qwe', 'rty', 'yui',)"`

I have tried multiple times combining substr, str_replace. It just gives me wrong results.

Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: `str_replace(',)', ')', $string);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard too late after I received some replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to replace `",)"` by `")"`

```
$string = "('abc', 'def', 'gah',), ('qwe', 'rty', 'yui',)";
$string = str_replace(",)", ")", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like
`str_replace(",)", ")", $string)`